# How do I use yii2-dashboard?

Tags: yii2, dashboard

I would like to use a dashboard for my system. I found this Yii2-dashboard module. I am not sure if it is like GII where you can create models, CRUD, etc. In short, does yii2-dashboard has a UI like GII? Or should I manually code it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As the docs says, you have to code a little bit: [Where do i go now - Yii2 Dashboard](https://github.com/ElijahGM/yii2-dashboard#where-do-i-go-now)

You can start adding panels on to your dashboard using this method

```
\Yii::$app->dashboard->addPanel($name,$view,$section);
```

The addPanel() function accepts 3 parameters

```
$name; /** name of the panel **/
$view; /** content of the panel **/
$section; /** section where the panel will be displayed**/
```